# Why does else function run even the elif statement is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm working on a take home exam and I completed it but only for one sample test it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```py
h = 'abcdefgh'
v = '12345678'
h_knight = (input('Please enter horizontal position of the knight (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h): ')).lower()
if len(h_knight) != 1 or h_knight.isalpha() is False:
  print('Horizontal input for knight is not a letter')  
elif not (h_knight) in h:
  print('Horizontal input for knight is not a proper letter')
else:  
  v_knight = (input('Please enter vertical position of the knight (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8): '))
  if v_knight.isdigit() == False:
    print('Vertical input for knight is not a number')
  elif v_knight.isdigit() == True and v_knight not in v:
    print('Vertical input for knight is not a proper number')
  else:
    h_bishop = (input('Please enter horizontal position of the bishop (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h): ')).lower()
    if len(h_bishop) != 1 or h_bishop.isalpha() is False:
      print('Horizontal input for bishop is not a letter')
    elif not (h_bishop) in h:
      print('Horizontal input for bishop is not a proper letter')
    else:    
      v_bishop = (input('Please enter vertical position of the bishop (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8): '))
      if v_bishop.isdigit() == False:
        print('Vertical input for bishop is not a number')
      elif v_bishop.isdigit() == True and v_knight not in v:
        print('Vertical input for bishop is not a proper number')
      else:
        idx1 = h.find(h_knight)
        idx2 = v.find(v_knight)
        idx3 = h.find(h_bishop)
        idx4 = v.find(v_bishop)
        if idx1 == idx3 and idx2 == idx4:
          print("They can't be in the same square")
        elif abs(idx1 - idx3) == 2 and abs(idx2 - idx4) == 1:
          print('Knight can attack bishop')
        elif abs(idx1 - idx3) == 1 and abs(idx2 - idx4) == 2:
          print('Knight can attack bishop')
        else:
          if abs(idx1 - idx3) != abs(idx2 - idx4):
            print('Neither of them can attack each other')
          else:
            print('Bishop can attack knight')
```

Inputs for the sample test which doesn't work: h,1,h,9.
It's supposed to display 'Vertical input for bishop is not a proper number' but instead it displays 'Neither of them can attack each other'which is an else condition as you can see above. I appreciate any suggestions to fix it.

Comment: I recommend you move the code that gets the position of a piece into a function. That way you won't have to repeat all that code for each piece in nested `if` blocks.

Comment: Stop using `x == True` and `x == False`. Use `if x:` and `if not x:`

Comment: You don't need `xxx.isdigit() == True` at all, since the previous `if` condition already checks that, and you won't get to `elif` if it's not digits.

Comment: You have a typo. When you're checking the bishop, you have `and v_knight not in v:` instead of `and v_bishop not in v:`

Comment: This would be a lot simpler without so much nesting. If `h_knight` is not valid, raise an exception, or continue getting input in loop until it is valid, etc. Then all the code that expects `h_knight` to *be* valid can continue unindented, rather than buried in an `else` clause.

Comment: Putting this code into a function would have prevented this error. So it doesn't just make the code easier to read, it also avoids some errors.

Comment: Getting rid of the typo has fixed my problem, thank you Barmar!

Comment: We haven't been taught about loops and exceptions yet. Thus, I did lots of nesting. I will try top simplify it now. Thank you too much for your precious advices!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check if the bishops postition is in `v`

This

```
elif v_bishop.isdigit() == True and v_knight not in v:
                print('Vertical input for bishop is not a proper number')
```

Should be this:

```
elif v_bishop.isdigit() == True and v_bishop not in v:
                print('Vertical input for bishop is not a proper number')
```

I guess you copy pasted and didn't change it

Comment: In the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, see the link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; there, see the bullet point regarding questions "*about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error*"; this particular case is the latter.